# Class as a parameter

Tags: c#, class, parameters

Within my function, I have hardcoded the name of a JSON class (called ExperienceLevel). Forgive the terminology, but this is a sublevel of the JSONMain class (i.e. JSONMain has a get/set for ExperienceLevel). It runs as expected.

However, I wish to modify the function to pass the name of any of my"sub" classes as a parameter for the function. In addition to ExperienceLevel, I have others. Of course, I also want to specify a property (field name) for any one of those "sub" classes.

Is it possible for the declaration to accept a class?

```
private List<string> FillComboBoxUsingPHP(string PHPfile, string fieldNameToRetrieve, ComboBox cmbBoxName)
```

And how would I call upon it:

```
List<ExperienceLevel> data = JSONMainResponse.ExperienceLevel;

            foreach (ExperienceLevel ep in data)
            {
                results.Add(ep.ExperienceName);
            }
```

Full function:

```
private List<string> FillComboBoxUsingPHP(string PHPfile, string fieldNameToRetrieve, ComboBox cmbBoxName)
        {
            cmbBoxName.Items.Clear();
            List<String> results = new List<String>();

            string submitLink =
                PhpURLStringBuilder(serverURL, PHPfile);

            string result = PostData(submitLink);

            JSONMain JSONMainResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONMain>(result);

            string success = JSONMainResponse.Success;
            string msg = JSONMainResponse.Msg;
            List<ExperienceLevel> data = JSONMainResponse.ExperienceLevel;

            foreach (ExperienceLevel ep in data)
            {
                results.Add(ep.ExperienceName);
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Classes:

```
public partial class JSONMain
        {
            [JsonProperty("success")]
            public string Success { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("msg")]
            public string Msg { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("data")]
            public List<TechProfile> Data { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("ExperienceLevel")]
            public List<ExperienceLevel> ExperienceLevel { get; set; }
        }
```

```
public partial class ExperienceLevel
        {
            [JsonProperty("ExperienceId")]
            public string ExperienceId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("ExperienceName")]
            public string ExperienceName { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: You might want generics `class JSONMain<T> { public List<T> Data { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the case for `generics`.
Using code below you can pass class as a generic argument and then, in the body of method, ask on passed argument and process accordingly

```
private List<string> FillComboBoxUsingPHP<T>(string PHPfile, string fieldNameToRetrieve, ComboBox cmbBoxName) where T: JSONMain
{
    cmbBoxName.Items.Clear();
    List<String> results = new List<String>();

    string submitLink =
        PhpURLStringBuilder(serverURL, PHPfile);

    string result = PostData(submitLink);

    T JSONMainResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);

    if (JSONMainResponse is JSONMain jsonMain)
    {
        string success = jsonMain.Success;
        string msg = jsonMain.Msg;
        List<ExperienceLevel> data = jsonMain.ExperienceLevel;

        foreach (ExperienceLevel ep in data)
        {
            results.Add(ep.ExperienceName);
        }

        return results;
    }
    //next types
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realised this wont work because of a more fundamental problem. My JSON response "data" section can be of type TechProfile or ExperienceLevel. I need to figure how to handle this first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get one or another property within the JSONMain object depending on an input parameter you don't have yet. Here's a mock of what I'd do without getting deeper.

```
// call it like this
FillComboBoxUsingPHP("", "", null, x => x.ExperienceLevel, x => x.ExperienceName);


 private List<string> FillComboBoxUsingPHP<T>(string PHPfile,
                                                 string fieldNameToRetrieve,
                                                 ComboBox cmbBoxName,
                                                 Func<JSONMain, List<T>> dataAccess,
                                                 Func<T, string> propAccess)
    {
        cmbBoxName.Items.Clear();
        List<String> results = new List<String>();

        string submitLink =
            PhpURLStringBuilder(serverURL, PHPfile);

        string result = PostData(submitLink);

        JSONMain JSONMainResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONMain>(result);

        string success = JSONMainResponse.Success;
        string msg = JSONMainResponse.Msg;
        List<T> data = dataAccess.Invoke(JSONMainResponse);

        foreach (T ep in data)
        {
            results.Add(propAccess.Invoke(ep));
        }
        return results;
    }
```